# Populate a text area by clicking an item on a list

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jlist

[image]I am trying to create a car GUI project where if I click on the name of a car in my list it will populate a nearby text box with car information. I tried using a ListValueChanges method but that did not work.

```
package vehicle;


import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class VehiclesGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ListSelectionListener{

public VehiclesGUI() {
    initComponents();
    Vehicle[] vehicle = new Vehicle[4];
    vehicle[0] = new Altima();
    vehicle[1] = new Model_S();
    vehicle[2] = new Taurus();
    vehicle[3] = new Volt();
    vehicleList.setListData(vehicle);
    vehicleList.setCellRenderer(new VehicleListCellRenderer());
}
private void vehicleListValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                        
    Vehicle vehicle = (Vehicle)vehicleList.getSelectedValue();
    txtDisplay.setText(vehicle.getName());
    vehicleList.addListSelectionListener( this );
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new VehiclesGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
```

**EDIT:**  Ive implemented the ListSelectionListener and the assListSelectionListener but the textbox still says txtDisplay

Answer (score 5):

> I tried using a ListValueChanges method but that did not work.

I don't see where you add the listener to the JList. You need:

1. for your class to implement ListSelectionListener
2. vehicleList.addListSelectionListener( this );

Check out the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for a working example. The tutorial example is a better approach because its not a good idea for the class to implement the listener, but I just gave you a quick idea of what is wrong.

Comment: I added the changes you requested and still nothing, perhaps i need to do something in the properties window that I am missing?

Comment: @DavidMoran, did you read the tutorial? Where in the code of the tutorial do they add the "listener" to the "JList"?